# Unet Unity Checking when a Client has Spawned and Destroyed the Player Prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-networking

I need to enable a script on the player GameObject only if there is a minimum of 2 players on the server. How can I be sure on the server side that a client has spawned his/her player prefab after connecting to the server? Likewise, how can I know when the Prefab is destroyed just before a client disconnects so I can disable my script on the other players ?